# Como hacer un label transparente sobre un picturebox en C# WinForms

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2019

Quiero hacer que el backcolor de mi label sea transparente sobre un picturebox... He encontrado este codigo en internet pero no me funciona actualmente con visual studio community 2019.

```
    public formBinds()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        lblDesc.Parent = picContainerGreen;
        lblDesc.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
    }
```

Al iniciar la aplicacion con este codigo el label no se muestra y aparece solamente el picturebox. Mientra que si quito .Parent, este aparece como en la siguiente imagen.

[image: PictureBox + Label En Visual Studio Community 2019]

Agradezco todo tipo de comentario buena onda y constructivo

Comment: No tiene ninguna ciencia, es como lo estas haciendo. Fijate de que no te haya quedado el color seteado en la propiedades y haya algun conflicto ahi. No hace falta el Parent, para que lo seteas

Comment: El color seteado del label.BackColor es de Transparent y el de ForeColor es White. Aun sigo sin conseguir que este tome el color de fondo del picturebox y no del panel que se encuentra abajo del picturebox...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En las pruebas que hice obtuve el mismo problema, el label no se muestra.

Pero encontré la [respuesta de Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9387562/6884087) en StackOverflow en ingles que funciona perfecto.

```
public formBinds()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var pos = this.PointToScreen(lblDesc.Location);
    pos = picContainerGreen.PointToClient(pos);
    lblDesc.Parent = picContainerGreen;
    lblDesc.Location = pos;
    lblDesc.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
}
```

Comment: Utilice el codigo, pero el label al iniciar el form no se muestra. La propiedad Visible se encuentra en true para el picture y en el label, pero al momento de colocar Parent, este desaparece... Que puede ser? Muchas gracias por tu respuesta

Comment: @GhostY, Me parece extraño, en mi proyecto de prueba funciona perfecto. Acabo de editar el código para ponerle el nombre `picContainerGreen` al pictureBox1 paar que puedas copiar y pegar.

Comment: Acabo de cambiar el codigo desde formBinds() hacia  un boton() y ahora me aparece transparente con el texto, el unico problema es que se encuentra desalineado completamente... eso ya es tema del Location. Funciona perfectamente tu codigo, pero si a alguien mas no le funciona le recomiendo cambiarlo a un boton o al form_load. Muchas gracias Pablo!